# Spring logout GET vs POST

Tags: java, spring

I am learning spring at the moment and just made first simple logout with Spring. I know that I logout by makeing a POST request to path "/logout". But why is GET not enough? I tried Googling but it seems i have wrong search words, since I get only results on "why cant I login to x"

Comment: This might help https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout

Comment: Please include the code and a [mre]. We cannot help you without knowing what it is that you have done.

Comment: Hello Rick, This was not intended as an code review or problem as such, but as curiosity why POST is used in logout and not GET, since my google -fu failed me :)

Comment: Thank you very much  implosivesilence. That link was really helpfull and explained the reasons really nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major reason is that it's easy to trick the user into clicking on a link to `/logout` or even forging the request via JavaScript. This is a nuisance at the least and can be the beginning of some kind of attempt to get the user to enter credentials into a fake site. Using POST brings all of the CSRF protection into play, making malicious or accidental logging out more difficult.